# changing states using stateProvider in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('Login',{
    url:'/login',
    onEnter:["$state","$localStorage", '$rootScope' , '$ionicViewSwitcher', function($state,$localStorage, $rootScope, $ionicViewSwitcher){
        if((typeof($localStorage.userInfo)!== 'undefined') && (Object.keys($localStorage.userInfo).length !== 0)) {
                       $ionicViewSwitcher.nextTransition('none');
                     $state.go("Deployment");

        }
    }],
    templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl'

  })
  .state('Deployment',{
    url:'/deployment',
    templateUrl:'templates/deployment.html',
    cache : false
  })
  .state('Bill',{
    url:'/bills',
    templateUrl:'templates/bills.html',
    cache : false
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
           var $state = $injector.get('$state');
            $state.go('Login');
        });

});
```

controller:

```
$scope.billsDetails=function(deploymentId,startingDate,name){
      $state.go('Bill', {}, {reload:true});
}
```

When It goes to state `Bill`, the url changes from the url of previous state. to that of Bill and then instantly changes to `localhost:8100/#`.

That is:

1.`localhost:8100/#/urlOfPreviousState`

2. `localhost:8100/#Bill`
3. `localhost:8100:/#`

Even though it stays at the Bill state, url changes to #. I am concerned since it is creating problem with back button. On first tap at back button, it goes to 
`/#/Bill` and on second to `/#/urlOffpreviousState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the state like this:

```
$state.go('Bill');
```

Comment: I did. It did not make any difference

Comment: I used ui-sref instead and it fixed the issue :)